# Nextjs not parsed JSON

Tags: next.js

I have problem.In dev mode Nextjs parse JSON. But in production mode json state json. (Amazing)
config.next.js

```
const {webpack} = require("next/dist/compiled/webpack/webpack");
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    fs: false,
    path: false,
    dns: false,
    net: false,
    tls: false,
    pageExtensions: ["middleware.tsx"],
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['pg']
}

module.exports = nextConfig
module.exports = {
    webpack5: true,
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^pg-native$/ }))
        config.resolve.fallback = {
            fs: false,
            path: false,
            dns: false,
            net: false,
            tls: false
        };

        return config;
    },
};
```

rewrite nextjs config

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to configure your Next.js application to handle JSON parsing differently in development mode compared to production mode. To achieve this, you can use a custom Webpack configuration in your next.config.js file. You can use conditional logic to handle JSON parsing differently based on the environment.

Here's an example of how you can rewrite your next.config.js file:

```
const { webpack } = require("next/dist/compiled/webpack/webpack");

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const nextConfig = {
  fs: false,
  path: false,
  dns: false,
  net: false,
  tls: false,
  pageExtensions: ["middleware.tsx"],
  serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['pg'],
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^pg-native$/ }));
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      fs: false,
      path: false,
      dns: false,
      net: false,
      tls: false,
    };

    // Handle JSON parsing differently based on the environment
    if (!isProduction) {
      // In development mode, parse JSON
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      });
    } else {
      // In production mode, use a different JSON loader or parser
      // You can customize this part based on your production needs
      // For example, you can use 'json-loader' or any other JSON parsing library.
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      });
    }

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

In this configuration, we first check if the environment is in production mode (isProduction). If it's not in production mode, we use the json-loader to parse JSON files in the development environment. You can customize the production JSON loader or parsing mechanism based on your specific requirements.

Make sure to adjust the production JSON parsing part to match your actual production setup for JSON parsing.

Remember to install json-loader if you haven't already by running:

```
npm install json-loader --save-dev
```

This configuration should help you handle JSON parsing differently in development and production modes in your Next.js application.